# Sequence $\{x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3,\dots\}$ is convergent iff sequences $\{x_n\}$, $\{y_n\}$ are convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> If {$x_n$}, {$y_n$} are two bounded sequence {$z_n$} be a sequence defined by {$z_1=x_1,z_2=y_1,z_3=x_2,z_4=y_2 \cdots$}. Prove that sequence {$z_n$} is convergent iff {$x_n$},{$y_n$} are convergent and converges to same limit.

**MY PROOF**: If {$z_n$} is convergent $\lim{z_n=l}$:
Define two subsequence of {$z_n$}, namely {$z_{2n}$} and {$z_{2n-1}$} which will also be convergent and will converge to same limit $l$.

Hence {$x_n$}, {$y_n$} converges to same limit if {$z_n$} is convergent.

Now if {$x_n$}, {$y_n$} converges to same limit let say $l$ then we have two subsequence of  {$z_n$} ,{$z_{2n}$} and {$z_{2n-1}$} which converges to same limit hence {$z_n$} converges.

IS this proof correct?

**EDIT:** Rewriting second proof.

if  {$x_n$}, {$y_n$} converges to same limit let say $l$,

since $\lim x_n =l, \exists$ $k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ for given $\epsilon$ such that,
$$|x_n-l|<\epsilon,  \forall n \ge {k_1}$$

since $\lim y_n =l, \exists$ $ k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ for given $\epsilon$ such that,

$$|y_n-l|<\epsilon,  \forall n \ge {k_2}$$
Let $k=\max(k_1,k_2)$,so
$$|x_n-l|<\epsilon,  \forall n \ge {k}$$
$$|y_n-l|<\epsilon,  \forall n \ge {k}$$
since {$x_n=z_{2n-1}$} and {$y_n=z_{2n}$}
so, $$|z_n-l|<\epsilon,  \forall n \ge {k}$$

hence $\lim z_n=l$.

Comment: The second part looks like 'hand-waving'. You should write out an $\epsilon ,n_0$ proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is it correct now?

Comment: Feels like something is missing in the original statement - like x and y need to converge to the same limit.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor it's mentioned in question. Prove that sequence ${z_n}$ is convergent iff {$x_n$},{$y_n$} are convergent and converges to same limit.

Comment: oh sorry - I was looking at the title

Comment: Your last equality is valid for $n\geq 2k-1$

Comment: @SacAndSac why for n$\ge$ 2k-1

Comment: @SacAndSac you there?

Comment: @SaurabhRana With the 2 previous lines, you have $|z_{2k-1}-l|<\varepsilon$, $|z_{2(k+1)-1}-l|<\varepsilon,...$ and $|z_{2k}-l|<\varepsilon$, $|z_{2(k+1)}-l|<\varepsilon,...$